# String does not match when a it contains text after parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex, string

This works:

```
str = "California (LA) rocks"
match_string = "rocks"
str.match(match_string) # => #<MatchData "rocks">
```

Why does this not work?

```
match_string = "(LA) rocks"
str.match(match_string) # => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the parenthesis for `match` to work, otherwise they will be interpreted as part of the regex pattern (i.e. as a *capturing group*), and not as part of the string to be matched.

To escape the parenthesis you can use a `\`:

```
match_string = '\(LA\) rocks'
str.match(match_string)
#=> #<MatchData "(LA) rocks">
```

Notice the use of *single quotes* (`'`) instead of *double quotes* (`"`); if you want to use *double quotes* instead, you will need to use double `\`:

```
match_string = "\\(LA\\) rocks"
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the argument of `match` is converted into a regex. In particular, the parentheses in `"(LA) rocks"` are interpreted as meta characters, not as literal parentheses. In fact, the following matches:

```
"California LA rocks".match("(LA) rocks")
# => #<MatchData "LA rocks" 1:"LA">
```